# onclick shows duplicate json results inside view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data which are returned from my controller and thouse results are properly displayed as json inside js which appends div inside my view to show these data.
Now I have problem that with every click div is appended to +1 row to show same data.
How to delete these div on click action before appending new div.

```
 success: function (result) {
            var data = null;
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                data = '<div>' + item.Id + ' ' + item.Title + '</div>';
                $("#tab-" + item.PropertyType).append(data);
            });
```

Comment: Check how many actual ajax requests are run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you add a new set of divs you can delete all divs which have a parent div
 whose name is starting with "tab-"

```
success: function (result) {
        var data = null;
        $("[id^='tab-'] div").remove();
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            data = '<div>' + item.Id + ' ' + item.Title + '</div>';
            $("#tab-" + item.PropertyType).append(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 success: function (result) {
        var data = null;
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            $("#tab-" + item.PropertyType).children('div').remove(); //remove any divs inside the tab 
            data = '<div>' + item.Id + ' ' + item.Title + '</div>';
            $("#tab-" + item.PropertyType).append(data);
        });
```

**OR:** Replace the entire content of the tab on success:

```
success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            $("#tab-" + item.PropertyType).html('<div>' + item.Id + ' ' + item.Title + '</div>');
        });
```